# inter thread communication between java web application and web service

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, jax-ws

some premise changed on my original question posted in [inter-thread communication between java application and jax-ws web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478524/inter-thread-communication-between-java-application-and-jax-ws-web-service) ( i am also simplifying the question to make it simpler to understand (and hence get answered)... hope that's ok with the moderators.)

a web service thread (THREAD-1) places a request on a socket and goes to sleep waiting for the response. another listener thread (THREAD-2) (running as a separate web application, once it receives the response) has to wake up THREAD-1 out of its sleep.

how do i do that ( in a push notification way)?

They both have access to a database table. The THREAD-1 can put its unique id in the table before it goes to sleep. THREAD-2, once it receives the response and determines it belongs to THREAD-1, it updates the appropriate row in the database table. Now THREAD-1 can do polling (at regular intervals) on the database table to check if the response has arrived.

But I am looking to do it in a push-notification way. The THREAD-1 should be notified right away when the response has arrived without it having to poll every few seconds.

Comment: first reaction while reading this: *don't do that*. Second: *don't do it yourself*. This is message queuing. So find a solution/product/framework that lets you process message queuing on top of your database.

Comment: I think message queues are better suited for asynchronous communication, in my case THREAD-1 cannot put the request in a queue and forget about it - it infact has to wait in blocking mode to get its response back to update its calling client (web service client in this case) about the response received. That was my first reasoning about why i shouldn't use message queues in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If your backend request completes quickly and you won't have a torrent of client requests to handle, you can have the web service wait for a response over the same socket it just opened. It can block waiting to read the response.

However, if you have access to Servlet 3.0 (e.g. Tomcat 7), you can use [asynchronous HTTP requests](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html). It allows you to release the thread handling the web service client back into the pool without responding to the client's request. When a response message arrives from the backend service, the grabs the appropriate web service client request from the servlet container and sends the final response back to the web service client.

Comment: that would be the easiest to implement and i am going to confirm this design tomorrow with the legacy platform team *(we are opening socket to the legacy platform in this case). they told me yesterday that THREAD-1 sends a request to the socket and releases the handle on the socket. This way since this web service is going to get called by multiple web clients (multiple users hitting the web service on internet) they can all put the requests in parallel fashion and the responses can come back whenever they do.  if we do what you suggested the throughput will decrease dramatically

Comment: I was under the impression that these backend requests completed quickly. Therefore, see my edit.

Comment: thx for your suggestion @David Harkness - this is like a hybrid solution which doesn't seem to require working with threads wait/notify pattern and automatically takes care of matching the responses with their corresponding requesting threads.. (wishful thinking - i will confirm this after reading that link, just took a quick look for now and it looks _PROMISING_) ..

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the comment suggest: better don't try to implement this yourself. However, basically you could use standard Java thread-synchronization with wait()/notify()

- Thread-1 sets of remote call to Thread-2 together with a unique call-ID.
- Thread-1 does now `wait()` on a synchronization object (instead of `sleep()`)
- Thread-2 does the work and to return the result it calls some remote callback method in the JVM Thread-1 resides in - call-ID is passed together with the result
- The callback method on the Thread-1 side makes the result available via call-ID and wakes up all waiting threads by means of `notifyAll()`
- Threads incl. Thread-1 check if their result arrived, if yes they continue to work if no the `wait()` again.

Pseudo code for the Thread-1 side:

```
HashMap<String, Object> results;

// Called by Thread-1 to access Thread-2
public void doIt() {
    String callId = "aUniqueCallId";
    Object result = null;
    remoteCallToThread2(callId);
    synchronized(results) {
        while((result = results.remove(callId)) == null) {
            results.wait();
        }
    }
    doSomethingWith(result);
}

// Called remotely by Thread-2 when result is available
public void callback(String callId, Object result) {    
    synchronized(results) {
        results.put(callId, result);
        results.notifyAll();
    } 
}
```

Of course this is just the basic idea and can not be used as such, there's a lot of stuff to be considered here.

Comment: thanks for your detailed response @lost. But I would appreciate if you can comment on my reasoning to not go with message queue based solution for this. **Another thing** is when THREAD-1 (one instance of web service call from web CLiENT-1) sends a request (through a socket) it has to release that socket right after it sends the request. 

There's another listener thread that keeps listening on that socket for responses, but those responses can come out of order, so this listener thread has to look at each response and notify the appropriate waiting thread that its response has arrived.

Comment: it would be great if anyone (including @Arne ) - can explain how this functionality could be achieved with a message queue.. I certainly would prefer that route coz I wouldn't have to deal with threads in that much detail..

Comment: My answer is independent of how the callback from Thread-2 comes in. It could be done with a direct WS call originating from Thread-2, it could also come in by means of a message over an MQ system. If you do not want Thread-1 to block then wait()/notify() is the way to go. It may very well be that what I suggested is already included in common WS frameworks when you just set off a synchronous WS call from Thread-1 to Thread-2 (don't know the details of such frameworks). If this is the case this would be the easiest solution for you. You have to check out the properties of your framework.

Comment: @roobanbajwa if you follow David Harkness's hint to asynchronous HTTP you would use some kind of message queue. lost's skeleton might also be sufficient if you really want to implement that yourself. From your other posts I understood that THREAD-2 is calling legacy software and I wonder why you decouple that at all. Why not just call that legacy software directly from THREAD-1? Is the legacy software not thread safe? No problem, synchronize the calls. Afraid of scalability? Again: go for asynchronous HTTP. And to your reasoning on message queues: they may be used either way: sync and async.

Comment: I looked at the Thread wait/notify pattern: 
Reference : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html - It mentions **"Because notify doesn't allow you to specify the thread that is woken up, it is useful only in massively parallel applications"**

**I have an issue with this** - in my case I would like to wake up the specific thread only (the specific thread that sends a request and then waits for its response) and not notifyAll (that will be inefficient)

but the notify method does not allow me to wake up a specific thread.. how do i solve this issue

Comment: I found this link that looks promising.. will investigate further and update here- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-spnotif.html